# Why Flat module is 'flat'?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, terminology, flatness

I've been reading about 'flat module' in Dummit and foote algebra book.

It is a R-module that preserves exactness after tensoring it to any exact sequence of R-module. (i.e., It preserves injectivity.)

I'm wondering why its name is 'flat'.

I guess it is geometric object which is somehow 'flat' in algebraic geometry.

I tried to find articles about it, But I couldn't.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/flat+module have a look at this link It might help

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6789/why-are-flat-morphisms-flat

Comment: Thanks! I will look at those links.